# Calculate table value based on previous result of the same column field

Tags: kdb

I have a table with below field values. I want to calculate column s based on previous s value and pos, so formula for s calculation is :

s : (prev s)+pos
//Assume 1st row has predefine value for s - in this case 30

Table:

t:([id:til 9] pos:9?til 100)

update s:30 from `t where i=0

```
id| pos | s 
--| ----|--
0 | 66  |30
1 | 99  |  
2 | 25  | 
3 | 95  |
4 | 83  | 
5 | 31  |
6 | 84  | 
7 | 28  | 
8 | 18  |
```

Expected Result:

for id=1,
s = (prev s)+pos, so

30(prev s)+99(pos) = 129

for id=2,
129+25 = 154

for id=3,
154+95= 249

How can I calculate "s" dynamically using q query ?

Result should be:

```
id| pos | s 
--| ----|--
0 | 66  |30
1 | 99  |129  
2 | 25  |154  
3 | 95  |249 
4 | 83  |332  
5 | 31  |363 
6 | 84  |447  
7 | 28  |475  
8 | 18  |493
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one method - if you fill (`^`) `s` with `pos`, you can perform a running sum using `sums`:

```
q)update sums pos^s from([]id:til 9;pos:66 99 25 95 83 31 84 28 18;s:30,8#0N)
id pos s
----------
0  66  30
1  99  129
2  25  154
3  95  249
4  83  332
5  31  363
6  84  447
7  28  475
8  18  493
```

Comment: Thanks Cathal. Yeah , it works for this data, however this is just an example to solve complex problem where I want to fetch previous value of the variable which is computed dynamically. For example - let's say my s is calculated like - s: (prev(s) * prev(pos))%pos and this newly calculated s is used for next row's calculation as a previous value of s (prev s)

Comment: Something like that is a bit more involved... does this work for you? `update s:("f"$first[s],first[s]%\1_(%':)pos)from t`.

Comment: It works perfectly. But I don't understand ,how did you calculate prev(s) ? I am struggling to refer calculated result of previous s. If I take prev(s) it shows null for all other records except for the i = 1 which takes value of 30 for i=0 . For other records it doesn't have updated value of s in previous record so I get null

Comment: I'm using [each-prior](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-prior) & [scan](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#binary-application) in this approach to divide & multiply as you described. We don't want to change the first `pos` so I've dropped it using `1_`, and then add it back at the end (`first[s],`). We use `first[s]` as the seed value for the scan operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example in its simplest (generalised) form can be:

```
q)t:([]id:til 9;pos:66 99 25 95 83 31 84 28 18)
q)
q)update s:-36(+)\pos from t
id pos s
----------
0  66  30
1  99  129
2  25  154
3  95  249
4  83  332
5  31  363
6  84  447
7  28  475
8  18  493
```

Your second suggestion I think can be something like:

```
update s:{(x*y)%z}\[30;1^prev pos;pos] from t
```

Depending on what your seed value (30) is and depending on how you treat the non-existent "prev" pos on the first run.